# C# WinForm PrintPreviewDialog: Print Preview to Display Multiple Labels Per Page

Tags: c#, winforms, print-preview

I have a WinForm for creating Labels.

It calls a `PrintPreviewDialog` and displays information using the `PrintPageEventArgs` in the `PrintDocument`'s `PrintPageEventHandler`.

```
void Document_Printed(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e) {
  // Code goes here
}
```

If the Label is a small address label going to an 8.5x11 Letter, instead of seeing a single Label in the `PrintPreviewDialog`, I want to see the number of Labels that fit on that `PageSettings.PaperSize`.

Example: Say four (4) items fit on the selected media (Avery Printer Label or anything).

- If my End User specifies from 1 to 4 Copies to be printed, I want my Print Preview Dialog to display all copies.
- If my End User specifies more than four (4) items, the Print Preview Dialog should show multiple pages (I've never tackled multiple pages before).

I can size my data to fit my Label size, but I do not know how to get my `PrintPageEventHandler` to display more than 1 Label on the `PrintPreviewDialog`.

Could someone show me how this is done? How do I display and print multiple Labels (Documents?) per Sheet?

**EDIT:** Here is my code, which is based on 2 RectangleF objects: pageRect and LabelRect:

```
void Document_Printed(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e) {
  if (printPreview == null) return;
  int labelSupport = 1;
  RectangleF pageRect = new RectangleF(0, 0, printPreview.Document.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width, printPreview.Document.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height);
  float fW = (pageRect.Width < LabelRect.Width) ? (pageRect.Width / LabelRect.Width) : (LabelRect.Width / pageRect.Width);
  float fH = (pageRect.Height < LabelRect.Height) ? (pageRect.Height / LabelRect.Height) : (LabelRect.Height / pageRect.Height);
  // START Portion I need HELP with!
  if (1 < LabelsPerPage) {
    if (Landscape) {
    } else {
    }
  } else {
    if (Landscape) {
    } else {
    }
  }
  // END (I think) Portion I need HELP with!
  SizeF ratio = new SizeF(fW, fH);
  Graphics G = e.Graphics;
  foreach (Label item in labelList) {
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Black)) {
      using (Pen p = new Pen(b)) {
        float x = ratio.Width * (float)item.Location.X;
        float y = ratio.Height * (float)item.Location.Y;
        float w = ratio.Width * (float)item.Size.Width;
        float h = ratio.Height * (float)item.Size.Height;
        RectangleF r = new RectangleF(x, y, w, h);
        G.DrawString(item.Text, item.Font, b, r);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT 2:** I need a way to print 2 or more documents on 1 page. Nothing has addressed this key point as of yet. That's the answer I need.

Comment: It might be useful to see some of your rendering code of the PrintPageEventHandler

Comment: Understood. A code sample has been added starting with the **EDIT:** section.

Comment: This looks ok. I would put a breakpoint at the top of the method though and walk it line by line to make sure that what you expect to happen is actually happening. For example, are you Size and Location values changing for each item in your drawing loop? Looks like they should but if you didn't assign these values correctly elsewhere then you might be drawing the same thing over again or each new label on top of the previous ones.

Comment: LOL. Sorry about that. I'm in the middle of trying to get this code to print multiple copies. When you requested the code, I pasted in what I have on screen at the moment, and removed irrelevant stuff.

Comment: If you mean the Size and Location of each item in the labelList, those *should* not be changing as they are passed in when this Print Preview wrapper is called.

Comment: That's right, they shouldn't. But... the code looks correct. I would then suspect the data upon which it is operating of being messed up somehow. Fire up your debugger. Btw, I don't see any drawing offset logic which assumes that the lableList items know where to position themselves? If not, then you need a running X and Y offset (initially 0 and 0) and incremented as necessary for each label drawn to properly place the rendering on the page.

Comment: Hey Paul. Actually, the WinForm passes a List<T> of the Labels (System.Windows.Forms.Label), so the Label Sizes and Locations are already specified - but **NOT** actual size! Hence the code that calculates their sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing pages after the first is actually really easy to do: just set the PrintPageEventArgs [HasMorePages property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs.hasmorepages%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to true.

The tricky part is knowing when to stop this by setting `HasMorePages` to false.  I've done this by storing the data for each print job in a List and using an index value to track where I am on this list.

Each time the PrintPage event fires I increment my index which I use in my List to feed the PrintPage event the particulars of the page I want to print, and if I'm on the last element I set HasMorePages to false.

```
void Document_Printed(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e) { 
   // Get data for this page.
   //xxx =  pageDataList[indexValue];

   // Code to print stuff.

   indexValue++;
   e.HasMorePages = (pageDataList.Length == indexValue);
}
```

This approach can work for you too, perhaps with the labelList I see in your code.  Since you're going to be printing in batches of four you'll obviously have to adjust the logic a bit but I think you get the idea.

Comment: You know, I saw the `HasMorePages` property, but I've just been *viewing* it, not *setting* it.

Comment: Rats. Pressing [CR] committed the comment instead of breaking to the next line. {sigh!} Anyway, I'll try this to see if I can get multiple little labels to print/display on an 8.5x11 sheet of paper.

Comment: I had to shrink my *virtual* page by the number of pages I wanted to show up on screen, but otherwise this did work!